# Solving a Matrix DE involving the KL divergence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, information-theory

If we let $U_\mu$ be a vector field that associates a direction vector $U_\mu(\pi)$ with each $\pi \in $ unit simplex. Each such vector field is associated with a system of ODEs:
$$
\pi'(u) = U_\mu(\pi(u)), \quad \pi(0) = \pi \in \text{Unit Simplex}
$$
I am working with the ODE:
$$
U_\mu \propto \nabla H(\pi|\mu) =\pi_i'(u) = \log \frac{\pi_i(u)}{\mu_i} - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n \log \frac{\pi_j(u)}{\mu_j} ~~~~~i \in \{1,2,...,n \}
$$
with condition: $\pi_i(0) = p_i \in$ Unit Simplex.

Where $H(\pi|\mu) = \sum_{i=1}^n \pi_i \log \frac{\pi_i}{\mu_i}$.
I am wondering how I could even show that a solution exists, and if it does, how I would tackle a problem like this given the dependencies of equation $i$ on all $j=1,2,..,n$? Or if this kind of equation can only be solved numerically?

Comment: Well, at the interior of unit simplex the vector field is well-defined and it's a well-behaving vector field (even smooth). So, you can expect that everything is OK inside unit simplex. Are you sure that there's no typo in your equations?

Comment: @Evgeny which part did you think was incorrect? i think i've got the equation down right, i've edited to have the exact expression

Comment: The system as it's written now behaves badly at the border of simplex (for example,when you have $\mu = (1, 0, \dots, 0)$). I'm not absolutely sure but usually this (I mean, zero values substituted to the logarithm) are "fixed" when you have expressions similar to $z \ln z$ -- the substitution is OK then. I thought that your system lacks $\pi_i$ multipliers before the logarithms, but, again, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @Evgeny I've coped it as is from the paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.5376 page 14

Comment: Hm, okay. Well, it seems to be not a big problem if you're okay with interior of simplex.

Comment: @Evgeny so are you saying if we restrict out initial points to the interior of the unit simplex it is easy to have a solution ?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Every time logarithm stays away from zero values, the RHS of this system of ODEs is well-defined and is a nice smooth function, so in $(0, +\infty)^n$ (and inside simplex, of course) the local existence of solution is guaranteed.

Comment: @Evgeny so any ideas on how to actually attempt solving it?

Comment: At this moment I have no idea. What exactly do you want from exact solution?

Comment: @Evgeny Just for interest, an analytic solution actually isn't useful in the context of the paper, but I'd like to know how to solve it if its possible